# Ask Ubuntu logo is quite wobbly

Tags: bug, design

Look:

[image]

Please fix. You could use [this sprite file](http://timonline.tk/files/img/logos/stackexchange/sprites.svg) (all text is converted into paths).

Comment: This is only visible at the most zoomed in level... I'd say it should be fixed but it's not on the top list of priorities

Comment: @ThomasW. I saw it when I downloaded the sprites.zip to use on my website (and it mattered then). Considering this is the only copy of the AU logo...

Comment: Good idea Tim. I agree it is wobbly and I think it needs a redesign.

Comment: so sad, looks like they did Illustrator AutoTrace on the orginal... A baby unicorn dies every time a designer uses that feature. :*(